# R CATEGORICAL VARIABLE VALUE

Tags: r

is there a command to see how a categorical variable is coded?

Example, I have a variable called HbA1c and the categories I see are <5.7 and >=5.7. I want to know what value does <5.7 and >=5.7 take (if it is a 0 or a 1 or a 2). I Need it for regression analysis.

I am sorry if this question has been addressed already but I was not able to find the post.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `x` is a *factor* (the technical name for a categorical variable in R), then `levels(x)` gives you the levels in order, so something like

```
setNames(1:length(levels(f)),levels(f))
## a b c 
## 1 2 3
```

will give you a correspondence table.

Your question in the comments isn't entirely clear, but if you wanted to run a regression with numeric values starting at zero, I would try something like:

```
mydata$n <- as.numeric(mydata$f)-1
```

(the numeric codes associated with factors always run from 1 to N; this gives you a numeric variable running from 0 to N-1).  Then you can run a regression something like this:

```
lm(y~n,data=mydata)
```

Comment: I used the following command:  `Names(1:length(levels(dat1$HbA1ckatnorm)),levels(dat1$HbA1ckatnorm))` and I get a table which shows the levels as        `1      2`. If I now want to recode the variable, I use the `recode` function from `library car`. My code looks like `recode(dat1$HbA1ckatnorm, "'1'='0';'2'='1'")` but I get an error showing `Levels: <5.7 >= 5.7` and of course, the recode function does not work.